# Get categories in hierarchical format from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL category table as below. In which `parent` field tells `ID` of parent category, and `hassub` field tells whether category has subcategory or not. (I am using PHP as base.)

```
************************************
| ID  | parent  | name   | hassub  |
************************************
| 1   | 0       | Nature | 1       |
| 2   | 1       | foo    | 0       |
| 3   | 1       | bar    | 1       |
| 4   | 3       | bar1   | 0       |
| 5   | 0       | Anime  | 0       |
************************************
```

Now to get all categories in hierarchical format, Is there any way to do this in as few as possible MySQL query?

> - Main Category 1
>
>   - Sub Category 1
>   - Sub Category
>       2
>   - Sub Category 3
> - Main Category 2
> - Main Category 3
>
>   - Sub Category 1
>   - Sub Category
>       2

What I am doing now is get all rows with `parent = 0` and then query for each one of them to get it's subcategories.

Comment: I can't think of a more straightforward way to do that.

Comment: When you say "hierarchical format", do you just mean a display format (in which case, nested bullets as per the example?), or some specific result-set data structure that will lend itself to formatting in PHP?

Comment: @Sepster, yes i want just nested bullets as in example. Nothing extra. Actually I want to use this simple format in website's sitemap.

Comment: One workaround solution (may be) is to, use longer way to get result, then save result in html, and use that html directly in page. Bad thing is have to update it every time if category table changes.

Comment: @user1995997 Yes I agree that you should let the DBMS do the "heavy lifting" as it'll be more efficient than your/our PHP ever will be.  I'd stop short of emitting HTML from the DBMS though, as this makes your result set very inflexible for future re-formatting (or indeed, completely different uses). Good rule: Avoid mixing logic with presentation where possible. I'd let the PHP take care of emitting the HTML _around_ the complete dataset returned.  As per my recent answer ;-) (although I haven't actually done any HTML formatting, just given you the bones/structure that might help you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was hand-written in a text editor... I don't have a dev environment handy so appologies if this is just plain wrong or contains typos.

But regardless I think the idea is clear/sound.

The `$sql` would be:

```
SELECT 
    parent.id as parentid,
    parent.[name] as parentname,
    child.[name] as childname

FROM
    category child

    left join category parent -- Can't exclude parents with no children, else they won't appear in the list!
    on child.parent = parent.id

ORDER BY
    parentid
```

And then the PHP would be:

```
function categoryLevels(){
    $bullet = "*"; // You can specify your HTML/CSS :-)
    $indent = "   "; // You can specify your HTML/CSS :-)

    $sql = "_as above_";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $lastParentId = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $parentId = $row['parentid']
        if ($parentId != 0) {
            if ($parentId != $lastParentId) {
                echo $bullet . $row['parentname']
                $lastParentId = $parentId;
            }
            if (!is_null($row['childname']) { // this line is psuedo-code! - don't know the php equiv for is_null, sorry.
                echo $indent . $bullet . $row['childname'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The gist of this is basically:

1. Get a result set of all categories (excluding those with no parents), sorted by the parent to which they belong
2. Iterate that result set, and for each change in parent, output a "header" with the parent name.
3. Output the child.

Edited this to be less complex (and faster). Now the SQL simply excludes the parent rows altogether, rather than excluding them with the `IF` statement in the PHP.

Comment: Unbelivably it works. With html code combined its working as I needed. Thanks @Sepster. +1 for you.

Comment: @user1995997 Nice! I've just realised though, with my recent edit (replaced `left` join with `inner`, and removed `if`), you'll lose categories that have no children.  So please revert to `left` join, and re-instate the `if` block.  Will update my answer.

Comment: @user1995997 And also realised that it now needs a check for null child... so that it doesn't echo an empty bullet.  Code updated (with some psuedo-code) to reflect this.  Thanks heaps for the votes/accept, I really appreciate it.  And re your thanks: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive approach

```
function getSubCategories($parent_id = 0){

    $sql = "select col1, col2,... from table_name where parentt_id = ".$parent_id;
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['category_name'];
        getSubCategories($row['category_id']);
    }
}

getSubCategories();
```

This will print all categories in hierarchical format.Same way you can use to generate the hierarchical categories format.

Comment: I am using this method already, but it sends many mysql queries. Say if I have 20 rows in table, then it will call 8 to 10 queries.

Comment: Then try self join.Hope so it will help.

Comment: -1 Isn't this what the OP is doing already, adding recursion is unnecessary complexity as there's only one level of hierarchy (I think?).

Comment: @ Sepster : Then please suggest me the solution for n-level categories situation. Its good to know new approaches.

Comment: Refer my answer.  As I said there I wasn't able to test it... would value your feedback.  Will take downvote off (when I can...) as your solution is actually really useful for future readers who may (will probably!) need more than one level, even though it doesn't address the OP's specific concerns re complexity.

Comment: @Arvind My edit was rejected (not sure why, it was basically a reflection of my above comment, without changing the body of your answer whatsoever), so I'm unable to remove my downvote.  If you edit your answer, let me know and I'll remove the downvote (and this comment).

Answer (score 0):

You could join the data (providing you know the depth to go to).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE`test` (
  `id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO test (id, parent, name) values
(1, 0, 'Nature'),
(2, 1, 'Foo'),
(3, 1, 'Bar'),
(4, 3, 'Bar1'),
(5, 0, 'Anime');
```

We know there are two levels so only one join is needed - a join is needed for each level and this is one of the many downsides to the adjacancy list model.

```
SELECT a.name AS 'Level 1', b.name AS 'Level 2' FROM test AS a
LEFT JOIN test AS b
  ON b.parent = a.id
WHERE a.parent = 0
```

This would give the output:

```
+---------+---------+
| LEVEL 1 | LEVEL 2 |
---------------------
|  Nature |     Foo |
|  Nature |     Bar |
|   Anime |  (null) |
+---------+---------+
```

From this output you could traverse the array and populate your bullet list.